# cost to update dictionary in dynamodb?

Tags: dictionary, amazon-dynamodb, cost-management

I am wondering if I have a field in my DynamoDB that has a dictionary of size 1KB, and I update one of the key-value pairs in my dictionary by iterating a number forward by '1', will amazon charge me for the 8 bytes it takes to write an integer, or will amazon charge me a 1KB write operation to change a small subset of my dictionary?

Comment: You can test this out by enabling the flag on the request that tells dynamo to return the consumed capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any write operation in Dynamo consumes at least 1 write unit, so for a 1KB (or smaller) object you'd consume 1 write unit even if incrementing a counter. But if the item is 2KB you'll consume 2 write units.

> Writes    Number of item writes per second × 1 KB item size

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html#ProvisionedThroughputIntro.Writes

Comment: Thanks, I turned on updateItem.returnConsumedCapacity = true and found returned that capacityUnits = 1. Seems like this could get expensive really fast and that if amazon 'rounds-up' to the nearest KB, it would be in my best interest to make sure that each field has at least 1KB of data in it to get the most value

Comment: "each field has at least 1KB" is ITEM based not field based, so you want to have the KB filled at item level eventually, but i guess it really depends on your use case